# Twitter API Basic Timeline Operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have a website where I am using the Twitter API to get my three latest tweets.  No problem there.  However, if I post a retweet, when the call is made for the latest tweets, it shows the beginning "RT @DennisDMZ" and the retweets, but the return is truncated to 140 chars including the RT @DennisDMZ string.

Also, if there are links, the anchor tags are not created and the crypted url just shows as regular text.  I set the parameter include_entities=1 in the API call, and it returns the url information, but it does not automatically add the anchor tags. It even shows the position of the link, so technically you could build the link dynamically but that would be difficult.

Is there a way to get around either of these problems?

Comment: I guess Twitter doesn't want you using your tweets on a private website.

Comment: I think they make it more difficult...I was able to look at the return object on Firebug with a console.log and see what is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they make it more difficult...I was able to look at the return object on Firebug with a console.log and see what is returned.  The full text is under the 'reseller_status' property and the url under the 'entities' property, The url is given and the character positions as well, so I wrote an insert function to insert the anchor tags at the appropriate positions.

Comment: Did you mean to edit your question...? You already posted this as a comment.

Comment: My comment was also the answer so I just copied it as the answer